# CSS trouble getting elements to center both vertically and horizontally using flex

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

[image]

Sorry for the beginner question but i have been stuck on this for a long time. I have am trying to use flex to center align the `div.Homepage` elements but i cant seem to get anything but the button to align horizontally.  I also cant get the text `TEST` to center.  My CSS is below:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Recoleta';
    color: #FFF;
    background: #111;

}

html, body {
    height: 100%;

}

.Homepage{
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}

.logo-social-image{
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

My React HTML is below

```
   return(
            <div className="Homepage">
                <div className="Name-social">
                    {view}
                </div>
                <div className="Pro-button">
                    <OutlinedButtons  isLoading={this.state.isLoading} isLoaded={this.isLoaded} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: I think you need to provide the HTML structure, too.

Comment: just missing `justify-content: center;` in the css

Comment: i added it under `.Homepage` but it does not change anything

Comment: what is the parent component then? whatever the parent of the content you want to center, needs that css

Comment: thanks John, i added it to the upper most parent created by react and it worked!  The word `TEST` is centered vertically but not horizontally.  Do i need to go into the child element to center that?

Comment: It could also be that you need to add width: 100%; to .Homepage

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide your HTML, I made an example of how to do it https://jsfiddle.net/L29h8oxs/

Add

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

To the parent div (I think it will be your `.Homepage`) and it should center the child for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `justify-content: center` to the class `Homepage`.

```
.Homepage {
  /*Keep your previous style*/
  justify-content: center;
}
```